# unable to install packages in R on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, package

I have R installed on my ubuntu 12.04 laptop, I tried to install devtools, slidify and a couple of other packages

The following error message is what I see for ANY package  (here shown for slidify) - When I am asked to select a mirror I have picked a couple -

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks !! Farrukh

> install.packages("slidify") Installing package into
>   ‘/home/azfarl/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’ (as ‘lib’ is
>   unspecified)
>   --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session --- Error in download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :    unsupported URL
>   scheme Warning message: package ‘slidify’ is not available (for R
>   version 3.2.4 Revised)

Comment: Sounds like you may have not built R with HTTPS support. Maybe try an HTTP CRAN mirror instead with `chooseCRANmirror()` before running `install.packages()`

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer -however I am asked to select a CRAN mirror and I am then told that "slidify" is not available for R 3.2.4 - So I do select a CRAN mirror - Shoudl I reinstall R in a particular way ?

Comment: Just use another CRAN mirror, maybe `https://cloud.r-project.org/`. The one(s) you are selecting might be broken / temporarily unavailable.

Comment: From the output, the **Error** is that the url scheme is not supported. This usually means as @MrFlick said you have chosen a mirror like the one @RHertel mistakenly suggests, starting with https. Instead, choose a mirror starting with http:. But yes, you should install R so that it has https support out-of-the-box. I believe that `sudo apt-get install r` is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Whatever mirror you choose, with or without https, you should use `sudo apt-get install r-base` and follow the instructions described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) if you really want to re-install `R`.

Comment: Hi Guys, I appreciate your responses - none of this works when I use chooseCRANmirror() I get a mesage : Error in download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) : 
  unsupported URL scheme - and I have tried several 
When I reinstall r-base I am told it is already uptdated-

Comment: @FarrukhAzfar, have you tried installing the package directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify) with the help of the `devtools` package?